# Theorem about projections and direct sums

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, direct-sum, projection

I'm in advanced linear algebra and our professor presented this theorem about projections and direct sums:

-If {P<sub>1</sub>,...,P<sub>r</sub>} is a complete set of orthogonal projections then V=V<sub>1</sub>⊕...⊕V<sub>r</sub> where V<sub>i</sub>=im(P<sub>i</sub>).

-Conversely, if V=V<sub>1</sub>⊕...⊕V<sub>r</sub>, then the map P<sub>i</sub>(v<sub>1</sub>+...+v<sub>r</sub>)=v<sub>i</sub> is a projection and {P<sub>1</sub>,...,P<sub>r</sub>} is a complete set of orthogonal projections.

He provided a proof of the first part that I struggled to follow. Now I am trying to prove the "conversely" part. I think that the steps would be to show that the map is indeed a linear map and projection. Then show that the set is orthogonal and complete. But I'm not sure where to even start with those.

Comment: The direct sum $\oplus$ that you are using is really an orthogonal direct sum in your case.

Comment: To begin with, what’s your definition of a projection?

Comment: @amd these are the definitions I have: 1) A linear map P:V->V is called a projection if P^2 = P. 2) Two projections P and Q are called orthogonal if PQ=0=QP. 3) A set of orthogonal projections is called complete if P1+P2+...+Pr=I

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts isn't it part of the proof to prove that they are orthogonal?

Comment: You can't prove the projections are orthogonal unless you assume the direct sum decomposition is orthogonal. That's what my comment was aimed at.

Comment: You should include those definitions in your question proper.

Comment: @amd I'm sorry I didn't include them in the original question. I thought they were implied. My question is how to prove the second part of the theorem.